# How do I use data tags to make a sign glow?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I use `/setblock` to make glow signs as if I were using a glow ink sac?

I am trying to make a machine with signs telling you what you can do. But I want glowing signs with color. The text is "Reset" and the color is red.

This is for version 1.18.2, if it is a different command for 1.19, please tell me both.

Answer (score 4):

I don't really see why you can't just use a glow ink sac on the sign. I don't understand why you need it for setblock but here you go:

```
setblock ~ ~ ~ oak_sign{Color:"red",GlowingText:1b,Text2:'{"text":"Reset"}'}
```

Comment: Thank you, it was because I was making a thing where when I summon a mob it makes a machine :)